# hr has weird gray border in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

When I view my site in IE7 the

```
<hr />
```

has a weird gray border around it.

**How do I get ride of it?**

Link to my site: http://julianjosephs.com/

Comment: does it have an outline? you could try setting outline: 0 none;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<hr style="border:0;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If `font-size:1px; height:0; border:0;` doesn't work, just use a plain ol div instead of an hr.